# Read NMEA data from gps device

Tags: java, sockets, networking, gps, nmea

I am working with gps system. I want to read data from GPS device. I am using NMEA protocol. I am getting Data from Device but it is some what like ecoded ASCII string which i don't get. So Is there any way to get desire data. My Code is as under..

```
// My Code //
ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(1500);
Socket s1 = ss.accept();
While(s1 != null)
{
     InputStream is = s1.getInputStream();
     BufferedReader br = new InputStreamReader(is);

     String result = br.readLine();
     System.out.println(result)l

}
```

but i am getting encoded out put or something. So reply me correct way to read NMEA data.

Comment: set up the correct baud rate

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't post the "encoded ASCII" string?

Answer (score 1):

if you are getting NMEA data, its should be something of format:

> $GPRMC,220516,A,5133.82,N,00042.24,W,173.8,231.8,130694,004.2,W*70

```
  1   220516     Time Stamp
  2   A          validity - A-ok, V-invalid
  3   5133.82    current Latitude
  4   N          North/South
  5   00042.24   current Longitude
  6   W          East/West
  7   173.8      Speed in knots
  8   231.8      True course
  9   130694     Date Stamp
  10  004.2      Variation
  11  W          East/West
  12  *70        checksum
```

Now you just need to extract Longitude,Latitude etc. using simple java.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is alphanumeric strings with some punctuation, then you need to know what the NMEA GPS data looks like.

There is a format to each line; a prefix that indicates what kind of data is on that line, and then a format I call "fixed width field" for the rest of the line -- 4 chars for this, 7 chars for the next, etc.

Searching for "nmea gps data" will give you full details on those strings.

If your data looks like garbage instead of strings of alphanumeric characters and occcasional punctuation, then you do need to get the baud rate straight.